# Java Component With JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jtextfield

I am trying to create a JFrame in Java, with a JPanel inside of it, which will hold a component. 
I know how to add components using
panelname.add(component);
But I am making a class based off a JTextField and want to add the entire CLASS as a component into the JPanel, but when I do, Eclipse tells me: 

The method add(Component) in the type Container is not applicable for the arguments (BetterText)
(BetterText been the name of the class)
So all it basically is, is a class with a JTextField setup with methods and such, but I want to add that class as a component to the JPanel. I looked at the JTextField.java class and cant see anything interesting there, it looks like an ordinary class like any other, but you are able to add an instance of that class to a JPanel, whereas with mine, you cant. 
Any help will be appreciated, thankyou.
Also, if you know the solution, please post an example class.

Edit: Added code.

```
public BetterText(String defaultText) {
    super();
    //Sets up the textFields colours and the defaultText to display in it.
    setProperties();
    hasDefault = true;
    this.defaultText = defaultText;
    textField.addActionListener(this);
}
```

Another edit:

It also extends JTextField already.

```
public class BetterText extends JTextField implements ActionListener {
```

Comment: Please add some code.

Comment: What does BetterText extend from?

Comment: BetterText should extend JTextField, you're probably using composition, not inheritance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your JFrame, JPanel and JTextField extend the correct classes (if they are custom classes).

Some pseudo code:

```
public class BetterText() extends JTextField{    
    public BetterText(){
        super();
    }   
}
```

And then to create the GUI:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
BetterText textField = new BetterText();
frame.add(panel);
panel.add(textField);
panel.pack();
panel.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Thankyou for the examples, I have done so, but it just tells me Change type of 'textField' to Component.

Comment: @user3640377 Strange, a JTextField is a component. Are you sure you didn't mistype somewhere? Maybe add some code.

Comment: Thanks, for some reason it magically started working after some fiddling around. Thanks again for the quick reply and all.

Comment: Just remember to extend your custom class, without it's are just another random custom class.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that you are importing javax.swing.JComponent, then make your BetterText class   inherit from JTextField.